# How to access SimpleExoPlayer instance inside MediaBrowserServiceCompat with PlayerControlView?

Tags: android, android-notifications, exoplayer, mediabrowserservicecompat, mediabrowser

I have been trying to build an audio podcast app in which I need one feature of playing audio that should show in the notification bar/ lock screen just like any other music app.

For that, I have used `SimpleExoPlayer` for media, and `PlayerControlView` for UI.

For feature, I have used `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` by following official [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice). I have taken the reference of [UAMP app demo](https://github.com/android/uamp) provided by Android Devs too.

But in all these, they are handling media through `MediaPlayer` rather than `ExoPlayer` and `PlayerControlView`

`MainActivity` have UI/view and instance of `SimpleExoPlayer`. Which I am creating inside the activity as follows.

```
// Creating common instance of PlayerView
        val renderersFactory = DefaultRenderersFactory(this@MainActivity)
        val trackSelectionFactory = AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory()
        val trackSelectSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(trackSelectionFactory)
        val loadControl = DefaultLoadControl()
        exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this@MainActivity, renderersFactory, trackSelectSelector, loadControl)

// Attachig player of playerview to the exoplayer
        binding.bottomSheetParent.playerView.player = exoPlayer
```

The problem is that `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` will have the player and the activity will have the view. No one of them will have both to be able to attach players to view.

So, how can I pass the player from Service (that is not Serializable or Parcelable) to Activity or how can I pass a player view to the Service?